# GruntJS does not watch all folders in project

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

Why doesn't the GruntJS watch for the **css/** folder?
But it successfully watches for **/js** folder.
Manual start function by default or any separate function using **grunt-cli** command `grunt` or `grunt cssmin` works correctly too...

My GruntJS code is:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

// 1. Вся настройка находится здесь
var d = new Date();
var y = d.getFullYear();
var bannerText = 'Created by Andrew Dyachenko ' + y + ''
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    uglify: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                banner: '/*' + bannerText + '*/\n'
            },
            files: {
                'js/main.min.js': ['js/main.js']
            }
        }
    },
    cssmin: {
      target: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'css/',
          src: ['*.css', '!*.min.css'],
          dest: 'css/',
          ext: '.min.css'
        }]
      }
    },
    watch: {
        options: {
            livereload: true
        },
        scripts: {
            files: ['js/*.js', 'css/*.css'],
            tasks: ['process']
        }
    }
});

// 3. Тут мы указываем Grunt, что хотим использовать этот плагин
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-newer');

// 4. Указываем, какие задачи выполняются, когда мы вводим «grunt» в терминале
grunt.registerTask('process', ['newer:uglify', 'cssmin']);
grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify', 'cssmin', 'watch']);
```

};

Comment: We probably need to see your directory structure to know for sure.

Comment: You don't need to see all folders tree, it doesn't matter - because manual function running is working fine, folders way in this both functions is simmilar. One function is working fine, the second with the same way is working only for js folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my problemm was in undefined bug. But now after small rebuild, everythin is working fine.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

var d = new Date();
var y = d.getFullYear();
var bannerText = 'Created by Andrew Dyachenko ' + y + '';

grunt.initConfig({

    jshint: {
        files: ['js/*.js', '!js/*.min.js'],
        options: {
            // eqeqeq: false,
            // curly: true,
            // es3: true,
            // es5: true,
            // noempty: true,
            // shadow: true,
            // unused: true,
            // boss: true,
            // debug: true,
            globals: {
                jQuery: true
            }
        }
    },

    uglify: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                banner: '/*' + bannerText + '*/\n'
            },
            files: [{
              expand: true,
              cwd: 'js/',
              src: ['*.js', '!*.min.js'],
              dest: 'js/',
              ext: '.min.js'
          }]
        }
    },

    cssmin: {
      target: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'css/',
          src: ['*.css', '!*.min.css'],
          dest: 'css/',
          ext: '.min.css'
        }]
      }
    },

    watch: {
        options: {
            livereload: true
        },
        files: ['<%= jshint.files %>', ['css/*.css', '!css/*.min.css']],
        tasks: ['process']
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-newer');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

grunt.registerTask('process', ['newer:jshint', 'uglify', 'cssmin']);
grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'uglify', 'cssmin', 'watch']);
```

};